# Just-installed package is not found

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I ran `sudo apt-get install docker`, assuming it would work because, y'know, that's how packages are installed.

Only once the install completed, when trying to run any docker command, I am told that docker is not installed, and that I should try to apt-get it.

I tried both `which docker` and `whereis docker` to try to run it from its location but both seem to indicate that docker is not actually installed. If I try to apt-get docker again, I'm told it is installed. I then removed and reinstalled docker to try to fix this, but the same thing is happening. What can I do to resolve this?

EDIT

command output:

```
j@devstack01:~$ sudo apt-get install docker -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/12.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 65.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package docker.
(Reading database ... 113727 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../docker_1.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker (1.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up docker (1.5-1) ...
j@devstack01:~$ 


j@devstack01:~$ which docker
j@devstack01:~$

j@devstack01:~$ whereis docker
docker:
j@devstack01:~$

j@devstack01:~$ docker
The program 'docker' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install docker
j@devstack01:~$

j@devstack01:~$ apt-cache policy docker
docker:
  Installed: 1.5-1
  Candidate: 1.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
jn@devstack01:~$

jfarzan@devstack01:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep docker
docker                                          install
jfarzan@devstack01:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the terminal outputs of the mentioned commands..

Comment: I would add formatted output for which and whereis, but there wasn't any - they did not give any output, indicating that they couldn't find a package named docker. apt-get install indicated a successful install, I can paste the output for that if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Whatever you got..

Comment: What are the outputs of `apt-cache policy docker` and `dpkg --get-selections | grep docker` ?

Comment: Do you want the `docker` container? coz just `docker` is system tray for GNOME..

Comment: Welp. That is certainly my problem. Sorry for being thick-headed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker` package available in Ubuntu 14.04 Universe repository provides system tray for GNOME2 applications.

Apparently, you want the docker container. The correct package for that would be `docker.io`.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

---

The package version in 14.04 Universe repository is 0.9.1. If you want to install the latest version follow [this official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/).